# Как произвести поиск через одно из полей составного ключа?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

Есть такие вот классы:

**Табличное представление:**

```
@Table("history_subscribe")
@Data
public class HistorySubscribe {
    @PrimaryKey
    private HistorySubscribePK historySubscribePK;
    // Остальные поля
}
```

**Составной первичный ключ:**

```
@PrimaryKeyClass
@Data
public class HistorySubscribePK implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    @Column("nt_id")
    private String ntId;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private UUID adb_id;

}
```

Хочу произвести поиск в таблице по полю `ntId`.

*Такое вот не прокатывает:*

```
public interface HistorySubscribeRepository extends CrudRepository<HistorySubscribe, HistorySubscribePK> {
    List<HistorySubscribe> findAllByNtId(String ntId);
}
```

*C ошибкой:*

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property ntId found for type HistorySubscribe!
```

**Как сделать правильно ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй примерно так:

```
@Entity
public class HistorySubscribe implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private HistorySubscribePK pk;

    // Остальные поля
}

@Embeddable
public class HistorySubscribePK implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private UUID uid;   

    // Конструктор
    // Геттеры
}

public interface HistorySubscribeRepository extends CrudRepository<HistorySubscribe, HistorySubscribePK> {

    // Поиск по полному ключу
    List<HistorySubscribe> findAllByPk(HistorySubscribePK pk);

    // Поиск по одному из полей ключа
    List<HistorySubscribe> findAllByPkId(String id);
}    

HistorySubscribePK pk = new HistorySubscribePK(...);
List<HistorySubscribe> list1 = findAllByPk(pk);
List<HistorySubscribe> list2 = findAllByPkId(pk.getId());
```

Если очень нужно использовать составные наименования полей, то о том как их использовать при составлении имени метода, можно почитать здесь: [Property expressions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions)